# MPAndroidChart: How do I get the corresponding chart x-value for a pixel point?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

How can I obtain the corresponding x-axis value (xIndex) of a pixel point in a ScatterChart?

I have been looking through the source code of the library and I think that one of the methods below (which I copy/pasted from the source code from the library [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/utils/Transformer.java)) can help. It seems `getValuesByTouchPoint` is the correct method but I don't know how to use it.

```
/**
* Transformer class that contains all matrices and is responsible for
* transforming values into pixels on the screen and backwards.
*
 * @author Philipp Jahoda
 */
public class Transformer {

/**
 * matrix to map the values to the screen pixels
 */
protected Matrix mMatrixValueToPx = new Matrix();

/**
 * matrix for handling the different offsets of the chart
 */
protected Matrix mMatrixOffset = new Matrix();

protected ViewPortHandler mViewPortHandler;

public Transformer(ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
    this.mViewPortHandler = viewPortHandler;
}

/**
 * Prepares the matrix that transforms values to pixels. Calculates the
 * scale factors from the charts size and offsets.
 *
 * @param xChartMin
 * @param deltaX
 * @param deltaY
 * @param yChartMin
 */
public void prepareMatrixValuePx(float xChartMin, float deltaX, float deltaY, float yChartMin) {

    float scaleX = (float) ((mViewPortHandler.contentWidth()) / deltaX);
    float scaleY = (float) ((mViewPortHandler.contentHeight()) / deltaY);

    if (Float.isInfinite(scaleX)) {
        scaleX = 0;
    }
    if (Float.isInfinite(scaleY)) {
        scaleY = 0;
    }

    // setup all matrices
    mMatrixValueToPx.reset();
    mMatrixValueToPx.postTranslate(-xChartMin, -yChartMin);
    mMatrixValueToPx.postScale(scaleX, -scaleY);
}

/**
 * Prepares the matrix that contains all offsets.
 *
 * @param inverted
 */
public void prepareMatrixOffset(boolean inverted) {

    mMatrixOffset.reset();

    // offset.postTranslate(mOffsetLeft, getHeight() - mOffsetBottom);

    if (!inverted)
        mMatrixOffset.postTranslate(mViewPortHandler.offsetLeft(),
                mViewPortHandler.getChartHeight() - mViewPortHandler.offsetBottom());
    else {
        mMatrixOffset
                .setTranslate(mViewPortHandler.offsetLeft(), -mViewPortHandler.offsetTop());
        mMatrixOffset.postScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
    }
}

protected float[] valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesScatter = new float[1];

/**
 * Transforms an List of Entry into a float array containing the x and
 * y values transformed with all matrices for the SCATTERCHART.
 *
 * @param data
 * @return
 */
public float[] generateTransformedValuesScatter(IScatterDataSet data, float phaseX,
                                                float phaseY, int from, int to) {

    final int count = (int) ((to - from) * phaseX + 1) * 2;

    if (valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesScatter.length != count) {
        valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesScatter = new float[count];
    }
    float[] valuePoints = valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesScatter;

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j += 2) {

        Entry e = data.getEntryForIndex(j / 2 + from);

        if (e != null) {
            valuePoints[j] = e.getX();
            valuePoints[j + 1] = e.getY() * phaseY;
        } else {
            valuePoints[j] = 0;
            valuePoints[j + 1] = 0;
        }
    }

    getValueToPixelMatrix().mapPoints(valuePoints);

    return valuePoints;
}

protected float[] valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesBubble = new float[1];

/**
 * Transforms an List of Entry into a float array containing the x and
 * y values transformed with all matrices for the BUBBLECHART.
 *
 * @param data
 * @return
 */
public float[] generateTransformedValuesBubble(IBubbleDataSet data, float phaseY, int from, int to) {

    final int count = (to - from + 1) * 2; // (int) Math.ceil((to - from) * phaseX) * 2;

    if (valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesBubble.length != count) {
        valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesBubble = new float[count];
    }
    float[] valuePoints = valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesBubble;

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j += 2) {

        Entry e = data.getEntryForIndex(j / 2 + from);

        if (e != null) {
            valuePoints[j] = e.getX();
            valuePoints[j + 1] = e.getY() * phaseY;
        } else {
            valuePoints[j] = 0;
            valuePoints[j + 1] = 0;
        }
    }

    getValueToPixelMatrix().mapPoints(valuePoints);

    return valuePoints;
}

protected float[] valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesLine = new float[1];

/**
 * Transforms an List of Entry into a float array containing the x and
 * y values transformed with all matrices for the LINECHART.
 *
 * @param data
 * @return
 */
public float[] generateTransformedValuesLine(ILineDataSet data,
                                             float phaseX, float phaseY, int from, int to) {

    final int count = (int) ((to - from) * phaseX + 1) * 2;

    if (valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesLine.length != count) {
        valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesLine = new float[count];
    }
    float[] valuePoints = valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesLine;

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j += 2) {

        Entry e = data.getEntryForIndex(j / 2 + from);

        if (e != null) {
            valuePoints[j] = e.getX();
            valuePoints[j + 1] = e.getY() * phaseY;
        } else {
            valuePoints[j] = 0;
            valuePoints[j + 1] = 0;
        }
    }

    getValueToPixelMatrix().mapPoints(valuePoints);

    return valuePoints;
}

protected float[] valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesCandle = new float[1];

/**
 * Transforms an List of Entry into a float array containing the x and
 * y values transformed with all matrices for the CANDLESTICKCHART.
 *
 * @param data
 * @return
 */
public float[] generateTransformedValuesCandle(ICandleDataSet data,
                                               float phaseX, float phaseY, int from, int to) {

    final int count = (int) ((to - from) * phaseX + 1) * 2;

    if (valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesCandle.length != count) {
        valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesCandle = new float[count];
    }
    float[] valuePoints = valuePointsForGenerateTransformedValuesCandle;

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j += 2) {

        CandleEntry e = data.getEntryForIndex(j / 2 + from);

        if (e != null) {
            valuePoints[j] = e.getX();
            valuePoints[j + 1] = e.getHigh() * phaseY;
        } else {
            valuePoints[j] = 0;
            valuePoints[j + 1] = 0;
        }
    }

    getValueToPixelMatrix().mapPoints(valuePoints);

    return valuePoints;
}

/**
 * transform a path with all the given matrices VERY IMPORTANT: keep order
 * to value-touch-offset
 *
 * @param path
 */
public void pathValueToPixel(Path path) {

    path.transform(mMatrixValueToPx);
    path.transform(mViewPortHandler.getMatrixTouch());
    path.transform(mMatrixOffset);
}

/**
 * Transforms multiple paths will all matrices.
 *
 * @param paths
 */
public void pathValuesToPixel(List<Path> paths) {

    for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
        pathValueToPixel(paths.get(i));
    }
}

/**
 * Transform an array of points with all matrices. VERY IMPORTANT: Keep
 * matrix order "value-touch-offset" when transforming.
 *
 * @param pts
 */
public void pointValuesToPixel(float[] pts) {

    mMatrixValueToPx.mapPoints(pts);
    mViewPortHandler.getMatrixTouch().mapPoints(pts);
    mMatrixOffset.mapPoints(pts);
}

/**
 * Transform a rectangle with all matrices.
 *
 * @param r
 */
public void rectValueToPixel(RectF r) {

    mMatrixValueToPx.mapRect(r);
    mViewPortHandler.getMatrixTouch().mapRect(r);
    mMatrixOffset.mapRect(r);
}

/**
 * Transform a rectangle with all matrices with potential animation phases.
 *
 * @param r
 * @param phaseY
 */
public void rectToPixelPhase(RectF r, float phaseY) {

    // multiply the height of the rect with the phase
    r.top *= phaseY;
    r.bottom *= phaseY;

    mMatrixValueToPx.mapRect(r);
    mViewPortHandler.getMatrixTouch().mapRect(r);
    mMatrixOffset.mapRect(r);
}

public void rectToPixelPhaseHorizontal(RectF r, float phaseY) {

    // multiply the height of the rect with the phase
    r.left *= phaseY;
    r.right *= phaseY;

    mMatrixValueToPx.mapRect(r);
    mViewPortHandler.getMatrixTouch().mapRect(r);
    mMatrixOffset.mapRect(r);
}

/**
 * Transform a rectangle with all matrices with potential animation phases.
 *
 * @param r
 */
public void rectValueToPixelHorizontal(RectF r) {

    mMatrixValueToPx.mapRect(r);
    mViewPortHandler.getMatrixTouch().mapRect(r);
    mMatrixOffset.mapRect(r);
}

/**
 * Transform a rectangle with all matrices with potential animation phases.
 *
 * @param r
 * @param phaseY
 */
public void rectValueToPixelHorizontal(RectF r, float phaseY) {

    // multiply the height of the rect with the phase
    r.left *= phaseY;
    r.right *= phaseY;

    mMatrixValueToPx.mapRect(r);
    mViewPortHandler.getMatrixTouch().mapRect(r);
    mMatrixOffset.mapRect(r);
}

/**
 * transforms multiple rects with all matrices
 *
 * @param rects
 */
public void rectValuesToPixel(List<RectF> rects) {

    Matrix m = getValueToPixelMatrix();

    for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++)
        m.mapRect(rects.get(i));
}

protected Matrix mPixelToValueMatrixBuffer = new Matrix();

/**
 * Transforms the given array of touch positions (pixels) (x, y, x, y, ...)
 * into values on the chart.
 *
 * @param pixels
 */
public void pixelsToValue(float[] pixels) {

    Matrix tmp = mPixelToValueMatrixBuffer;
    tmp.reset();

    // invert all matrixes to convert back to the original value
    mMatrixOffset.invert(tmp);
    tmp.mapPoints(pixels);

    mViewPortHandler.getMatrixTouch().invert(tmp);
    tmp.mapPoints(pixels);

    mMatrixValueToPx.invert(tmp);
    tmp.mapPoints(pixels);
}

/**
 * buffer for performance
 */
float[] ptsBuffer = new float[2];

/**
 * Returns a recyclable MPPointD instance.
 * returns the x and y values in the chart at the given touch point
 * (encapsulated in a MPPointD). This method transforms pixel coordinates to
 * coordinates / values in the chart. This is the opposite method to
 * getPixelForValues(...).
 *
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @return
 */
public MPPointD getValuesByTouchPoint(float x, float y) {

    MPPointD result = MPPointD.getInstance(0, 0);
    getValuesByTouchPoint(x, y, result);
    return result;
}

public void getValuesByTouchPoint(float x, float y, MPPointD outputPoint) {

    ptsBuffer[0] = x;
    ptsBuffer[1] = y;

    pixelsToValue(ptsBuffer);

    outputPoint.x = ptsBuffer[0];
    outputPoint.y = ptsBuffer[1];
}

/**
 * Returns a recyclable MPPointD instance.
 * Returns the x and y coordinates (pixels) for a given x and y value in the chart.
 *
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @return
 */
public MPPointD getPixelForValues(float x, float y) {

    ptsBuffer[0] = x;
    ptsBuffer[1] = y;

    pointValuesToPixel(ptsBuffer);

    double xPx = ptsBuffer[0];
    double yPx = ptsBuffer[1];

    return MPPointD.getInstance(xPx, yPx);
}

public Matrix getValueMatrix() {
    return mMatrixValueToPx;
}

public Matrix getOffsetMatrix() {
    return mMatrixOffset;
}

private Matrix mMBuffer1 = new Matrix();

public Matrix getValueToPixelMatrix() {
    mMBuffer1.set(mMatrixValueToPx);
    mMBuffer1.postConcat(mViewPortHandler.mMatrixTouch);
    mMBuffer1.postConcat(mMatrixOffset);
    return mMBuffer1;
}

private Matrix mMBuffer2 = new Matrix();

public Matrix getPixelToValueMatrix() {
    getValueToPixelMatrix().invert(mMBuffer2);
    return mMBuffer2;
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using MPAndroidChart 3.0.1**

I think the method you want is:

```
public MPPointD getValuesByTouchPoint(float x, float y);
```

Here's a snip from the javadoc:

```
/**
 * Returns a recyclable MPPointD instance.
 * returns the x and y values in the chart at the given touch point
 * (encapsulated in a MPPointD). This method transforms pixel coordinates to
 * coordinates / values in the chart. This is the opposite method to
 * getPixelsForValues(...).
```

To use it in your app, do something like this:

```
MPPointD point = mChart.getTransformer(AxisDependency.LEFT).getValuesByTouchPoint(x,y);
double xValue = point.x;
double yValue = point.y;
```

The parameters passed into the method `(float x, float y)` are your pixel co-ordinates that you want to be converted into x and y values in your chart.

Comment: Thanks you so much, it work like a charm! My error is that i create a new transformer object intead of take it from mchart.

Comment: @David, is that possible to get chart x and y point in pixel without tapping on it?