# How to add extra labels at specified points in LineChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I would like to add some extra labels to a `LineChart` ([MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)) like in the image below. Notice the "Advanced", "Novice" etc labels.

[image]

How could I add those to specified y-axis positions so they will always show up like y-axis labels but perhaps on the inside of the graph as shown - or on the right side if necessary?

*Update:*

All I needed to get what I needed was some `LimitLines` like this:

```
LimitLine noviceline = new LimitLine( SSGlobals.getWeightinPreferredUnits_fromPounds(standardweightsarr[2]) , getString(R.string.novice));
                        noviceline.setLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.accentline));
                        noviceline.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.accentline));
                        noviceline.setTextSize(12);
                        noviceline.setLineWidth(4);
```

I might style it up a bit more but so far the result looks like so:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options here.

You can see if the [LimitLines](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis) will fit your purpose - they are able to be configured with a label like this:

```
    LimitLine llXAxis = new LimitLine(10f, "Index 10");
    llXAxis.setLineWidth(4f);
    llXAxis.enableDashedLine(10f, 10f, 0f);
    llXAxis.setLabelPosition(LimitLabelPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM);
    llXAxis.setTextSize(10f);
    xAxis.addLimitLine(llXAxis);
```

You could also use a [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) with over the chart with TextViews for the extra info you want to add. See [this
 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083802/custom-view-of-limit-line-in-mpandroidchart) for something similar and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766419/mpandroidchart-how-do-i-get-the-corresponding-chart-x-value-for-a-pixel-point) for how to convert between chart values and on-screen pixel co-ordinates.

Alternatively, you can extend the renderer itself to draw your custom text. Please see [How do MPAndroidChart renderers work and how do I write a custom renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443787/how-do-mpandroidchart-renderers-work-and-how-do-i-write-a-custom-renderer) if you wish to attempt that.

Comment: Turns out, for my use so far, all I needed was to specify some lineLimits - added the code above for anyone interested.

Comment: @lostbaby great one - please add the code you used - you can add an answer if you like